# How to make the “last access time” field visible to anonymous users?

Tags: users

I have configured the user data display to show the last access information, but only me as I have the admin role can see it, anonymous users can not, nor even authenticated users:
So my question is how can I make that information to be seen publicly.

To configure the user visualization I went to "/admin/config/people/accounts/display" and used the "Layout Builder"

Some place I have seen, although not sure, that the field displaying this info is `{{ access }}`

Following image is from an admin session:

[image]

And Following image is from a non-admin user (authenticated only)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the *Last access time* field visible, you can use [`hook_entity_field_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_field_access/10).

```php
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
    
function mymodule_entity_field_access($operation, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, AccountInterface $account, FieldItemListInterface $items = NULL) { 
  if ($field_definition->getName() == 'access' && $operation == 'view') {
    return AccessResult::Allowed();
  }

  return  AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, it is not working, this is my 1st time doing hooks...  new module: modules/custom/user_public_info/user_public_info.info.yml → name: User public info
description: blah...
type: module
core_version_requirement: "^9.2|^10"
# Information added by me on 23-10-22
version: '1.x-0.1'
project: 'corlexim_custom_module'
datestamp: 1697978409
file: modules/custom/user_public_info/user_public_info.module → <?php
and your code changing: function user_public_info_entity_field_access(... then save enable module....

Comment: Then I went to the api page: of https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_field_access/10 and is a little different from what you sent me, so I tried adapting it but nothing...

Comment: To debug code whether control goes in hook, did you try to add logger & hit the page where last access field rendering, then checked in the logs, whether logger print or not.  One more thing I would like to mention you need to clear the cache once, after adding hook code

Comment: Thanks, yes clearing cache is a thing I do in every step... I will investigate how to add logger to do so, hopefully I'll find somehing

Comment: No, clearing cache don't change a thing... sorry I was out for a bit, now I check the logger thing...

Comment: can you try this :

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

function mymodule_user_access(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
  if ($entity->hasField('access') && $operation == 'view') {
    return AccessResult::Allowed();
  }  
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}

Comment: No, it does not work neither, and on admin/reports/dblog?type[]=php I get no errors whatsoever.. I've seen that module devel could help, do you think so?

Comment: Yeah you can try out to debug further , one more thing  it can be theme issue may be field missing in the template file or diff templates render for admin, authenticated, anonymous or something specific related to layout builder as you mentioned layout used

Comment: I could make ir for authenticated users, but not for anonymous with next code:   use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
  use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
  use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
  use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

Comment: /**
 * Implements hook_entity_field_access().
 */
function user_public_info_entity_field_access($operation, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, AccountInterface $account, FieldItemListInterface $items = NULL) {
  if ($field_definition->getName() == 'access' && $operation == 'view') {
    // Log a message for debugging purposes.
    $access = AccessResult::allowedIf(AccessResult::allowed() || $account->isAnonymous());
    return $access;
  }
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}

Comment: I have also added a line for debug with \Drupal::logger('user_public_info')->error('An error occurred: %message', ['%message' => $yourErrorMessage]); but I couldn't get useful information

Comment: As it starts working for authenticated it should also work for anonymous, if logger render for anonymous user then it means control goes in hooks

Comment: Yes, I have just found the problem... my fault.. I had the field user configured for "current user" when should be only "user", "current user" is the user that is configuring, while "user" is the actual user to whom the data is related... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yes, hooks controls this, I have tested uninstalling the module, I have to say that the code provided by https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/110803/mini did work. As the one I finally developed is also working I keep this last one, but as I say, mini's one is the key!! thanks mini

Comment: Thanks , I 'm glad that I can add some values to the community :)